# how to edit the primary form using a form that was created from the primary form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to edit a primary form(Form1) using a form that is created from its code(Form2). The way I have done it is that, when the event is triggered, the new form appears, and everything works, but I want it so that when a button is pressed, the original form is edited. The code I have tried is this:

```
 Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.startNewGame();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

By the way, I realise that this is creating a new instance of the form, I want to know how to edit the already existing instance of the form.

Comment: Could you show us the code that uses `Form2`?

Comment: The word "edit" appears to make little sense.  Do you actually mean "make visible" or "restore"?

Comment: @HansPassant I meant that I need to change a part of the form. I need to change a public class called startNewGame.

Comment: Also, @CoderDennis,  could you please clarify your question.

Comment: You mention `Form2` in the text of your question, but the code you list doesn't have any `Form2` in it. I was just asking you to include more of your code so we could see what you're trying to do with `Form2`.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the code of Form2 is hard to help you, but I will try. Instead of creating an instance of Form1, add a public property to form2 
`public Form1 PrimaryForm{get;set;}` and when you showin form2 set that property to `this`

Comment: Another option is to have the relevant data as properties on the `Form2` and use them after showing it from `Form1` as results.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to pass a reference of your Main Form to the child form when the child form is initialized.  You can then set the value of the mainform through the reference. See below for an example:

```
public class ChildForm1 : Form
{
    // Fields
    private MainForm _mainForm;
    private bool _value1;
    private bool _value2;

    // Default constructor
    public ChildForm1()
    {
    }

    // Overloaded constructor that accepts a container of values
    public ChildForm1(ValuesContainer values, MainForm mainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
        _value1 = values.Value1;
        _value2 = values.Value2;

        //Set a main form value
        _mainForm.Value = "This value was changed by ChildForm1."
    }
}

public class ChildForm2 : Form
{
    // Field
    private bool _value3;

    // Default constructor
    public ChildForm2()
    {
    }

    // Overloaded constructor that accepts a container of values
    public ChildForm2(ValuesContainer values)
    {
        _value3 = values.Value3;
    }
}

public class MainForm : Form
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // Default constructor
    public MainForm()
    {
    }

    // Simulated - Event method called when button is clicked for child form 1
    public void CallChildForm1()
    {
        ValuesContainer values = new ValuesContainer();

        // Set the values from the main form
        values.Value1 = true; 
        values.Value2 = true; 

        // Call the child form while passing in the container of values that we just populated.
        ChildForm1 childForm = new ChildForm1(values);
        childForm1.Show();
    }

    // Simulated - Event method called when button is clicked for child form 2
    public void CallChildForm2()
    {
        ValuesContainer values = new ValuesContainer();

        // Set the value from the main form
        values.Value3 = true; 

        // Call the child form while passing in the container of values that we just populated.
        ChildForm2 childForm = new ChildForm2(values);
        childForm2.Show();
    }
}

// Simple data object or container used to transfer information between complex objects such as forms and controls.
// These are also known as data classes or data transfer objects (DTOs)
public class ValuesContainer
{
    public bool Value1 { get; set; }
    public bool Value2 { get; set; }
    public bool Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best practice but is the simplest way to do it. Here are the steps;

1) in Form1 add a public method to edit whatever you want

2) in Form2 add a reference to type Form1

3) instantiate Form2 and set `InstanceOfForm2.ReferenceToForm1 = this;`

4) in  the event handler of Form2 use the reference to call your public method like

```
//inside some event handler
this.ReferenceToForm1.MyPublicMethodThatEditsTheDisplay();
```

One thing to remember is that Form1 is just an object like any other. The only thing preventing you from editing it anywhere you choose is the access level of it's properties (can't touch private fields, obviously) and the lack of reference. Everything beyond that is a matter of opinion and 'best practice' if you want to edit from anywhere, make the field public/provide a public method and pass/set a reference.